# Insert dynamic params into jQuery datepicker

Tags: php, datepicker

I'm trying to insert dynamic values into the

```
datepicker()
```

method.

I *can* insert a single variable like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php $date='2-15-2013'; ?>

<script>
var date = '<?php echo $date; ?>';
/* create an array of days which need to be disabled */
var disabledDays = [
        date,
        "2-21-2013",
        ];

/* utility functions */
function bookedDays(date) {
var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();

for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
  if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y, disabledDays) != -1 ) {
      return [false];
  }
}
return [true];
}

/* create datepicker */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: "+3M +10D",
  dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
  constrainInput: true,
  beforeShowDay: bookedDays
 });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
</body>
```

And the date '2-15-2013' is duly disabled. Why can't I then insert a string of values say:

```
$dates = ['2-21-2013', '2-24-2013', '2-27-2013'];
$unavailable = array();
foreach($dates as $date){
    array_push( $unavailable, $date);
}
$unavaildays = implode(',', $unavailable);
$string = "{$unavaildays},";
?>

<script>
var dates = '<?php echo $string; ?>';
/* create an array of days which need to be disabled */
var disabledDays = [
        dates
        "2-21-2013",

    ];
/* utility functions */
function bookedDays(date) { ...
```

with dates:

```
2-21-2013,2-24-2013,2-27-2013,
```

becoming disabled? My values are parsed on the server at runtime aren't they?

Comment: hard code the values, does it work? are you sure the function accepts the arguments in that form?

Comment: Yes, as above; I'm sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ahoo answered there is problem with quotation marks, but thats not all. It seems that `disabledDays` is also assigned in wrong way with `dates`.

I would recommend something like that:

```
<?
$dates = ['2-21-2013', '2-24-2013', '2-27-2013'];
$unavailable = array();
foreach($dates as $date){
    array_push( $unavailable, "'$date'");
}
$unavaildays = '[' . implode(',', $unavailable) . ']';
?>
<script>
var disabledDays = <?= $unavaildays?>;
disabledDays.push('2-21-2013');
```

This way you have proper initial array made from php, and than you can add more dates in javascript.

**Now, what was wrong:**

When you added `dates` this way:

```
var dates = '<?php echo $string; ?>';
/* create an array of days which need to be disabled */
var disabledDays = [
        dates
        "2-21-2013",

    ];
```

Resulting array was

```
[
    '2-21-2013,2-24-2013,2-27-2013',
    '2-21-2013'
]
```

Note the first array value, it is not 3 dates, it is string glued from 3 dates.

Comment: Cool:) Hope you also understood more about merging javascript and php params

Answer (score 1):

You missed quotation marks around dates:

```
$dates = ['"2-21-2013"', '"2-24-2013"', '"2-27-2013"'];
```